# event handler inside drop function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have three divs box with background color, when im drag and drop another div box002 to dragged to one of box ,

when im invoking a clear function from inside drop function using event handler for clearing background color its not calling the function.

how is it done?

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {

ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

}

function drop(ev) 

{

  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

  clear();

}
</script>

<script>

 function clear(event) 
{

$(event.target).css('background-color', 'none');

$(event.target).css('opacity', '0.0');

}

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/digitalarts/5nq746uy/2/

Comment: Where do you call the defined functions? Also when you call `clear()` you don't use the defined parameter.

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future. You just haven't passed the event object to `clear`. You want `clear(ev)`, not `clear()`, within `drop`. Event functions aren't special such that they always get an event argument automatically; they get an event argument as a result of how they're called. When you call one directly (rather than the browser doing it), you have to supply the argument. (When the browser does it, the browser supplies the event argument.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use something like [JQuery droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

```
$( function() {
   $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
   $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
         ui.draggable.css("background-color", "");            
      }
   });
});
```